# Is this translation correct? "一人说一句."

Tags: translation

一人说一句。
Does this mean, **"Each person say one sentence"**?
Is this correct?

Thanks so much!

Comment: hi, guys, express your opinion freely, just discuss a subject and collect suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

its by situations,

1. first, your translate is right when request some feedback
   (e.g. 你們一人說一句, 給我點回應)
2. sometimes it means too much responses
   (e.g. 你們一人說一句, 我怎麼聽得懂!)